# CakePHP: Check a user's group_id before deletion

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to protect administrators from accidentally deleting each other in CakePHP 2.4 by checking the group_id. I tried using the following delete method, but it deletes the user anyway and doesn't redirect. How do I return the group_id of the user and then redirect and display an appropriate flash saying "Administrators cannot be deleted"?

```
public function delete($id = null) {
    if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($user['User']['group_id'] == 1) { //Check user group
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Administrators can not be deleted'), 'flash/error');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }

    if (!$this->User->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User could not be deleted'), 'flash/error');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }

    if ($this->User->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted'), 'flash/success');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
```

}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have a typo in your code -- change your `=` to `==` ; then your if statement shouldn't be evaluating as true all the time

   ```
   if ($user['User']['group_id'] == '1')
   ```
2. Session is either a component (part of the Controller layer) or a helper (part of the View layer) -- it is not intended to be used in the Model, nor should it be used in the model, generally.  And redirect() is a controller method only.  Just have beforeDelete return false, and then in your controller have a check to see if the delete failed (i.e. it returned false), and if so, show your error flash message, and redirect.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it just deletes the user and doesn't redirect: I added the code I tried to the main question. Is `$user['User']['group_id']` the right way to get the group ID of the user being deleted?

Comment: Your `group_id` should be numerical, why are you checking it against a literal (`'1'`)? You should check `if ($user['User']['group_id'] == 1)`, although this shouldn't be the reason it fails because with `==` PHP will type cast accordingly to check for the value. In your controller you're calling `$this->User->delete()`, where is the supplied [`delete(id)` parameter](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html#delete)?

Comment: Thank you, this is pointing me in the right direction. Not only was my syntax wrong (= sets one variable to another, == compares two variables, === requires they be the same type), `$user['User']['group_id']`does not seem to be enough to return the group_id of the user being deleted.